# navigation bar and tabor does not change his color when switching dark and light mode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, viewcontroller

I want to change my app interface to light mode.

I implemented following code on all ViewControllers:

```
overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .light
```

When I switch to dark mode, the navigation bar and tab bar change his color to black. The rest is still white as it should be. The following image is dark mode on.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added in the Info.plist **User Interface Style** to light. Now it's working fine.